# most occuring characters in an array php?

Tags: php, arrays, character, counting

please help me to make a function to parse the following array and return an array containing the most occurring character case insensitive and excluding special characters, count Input

```
    $sentences = [
    0 => 'The tiger is the national animal of India',
    1 => 'The tiger is a large carnivorous mammal that roams the forests',
    2 => 'The tiger feeds on animals that also live in the forest',
    3 => 'The tiger does have a coat of orange with black stripes',
    4 => 'Tigers, regardless of their subspecies, are carnivorous animals',
    5 => 'The tiger is a protected species',
    ];

The code should output the following result: 

    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
    [sentence] => The tiger is the national animal of India
    [character] => i
    [occurrences] => 6
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
    [sentence] => The tiger is a large carnivorous mammal that roams the forests
    [character] => a
    [occurrences] => 7
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
    [sentence] => The tiger feeds on animals that also live in the forest
    [character] => e
    [occurrences] => 7
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
    [sentence] => The tiger does have a coat of orange with black stripes
    [character] => e
    [occurrences] => 6
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
    [sentence] => Tigers, regardless of their subspecies, are carnivorous animals
    [character] => s
    [occurrences] => 8
    )

    [5] => Array
    (
    [sentence] => The tiger is a protected species
    [character] => e
    [occurrences] => 6
    )

    )
```

I tried

```
foreach($sentences as $sentence) {
    $value = array_count_values($sentence);
}
```

Please help me to make a function for the above purpose

Comment: Did you try to do it by yourself first? show us what you tried.

Comment: no it was for my project

Comment: Then, you HAVE TRIED to solve it , haven't you?

Comment: You've just copied it from php manual. Please post what you've tried.

Comment: Always add question details to your question via an Edit (not a comment).  Please remove your comment after editing your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`array_map()`](https://php.net/array_map) to apply a function on each items. In this function, you could convert the string to lower case, split characters in an array (and [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) to remove spaces), in order to use [`array_count_values()`](https://php.net/array_count_values). Then, you could sort the array using [`arsort()`](https://php.net/arsort) to keep keys association and get the most used character in the top. Finally, you could use [`array_keys()`](https://php.net/array_keys) and `reset()` to get the first key and the first value of the array:

```
$sentences = [
  0 => 'The tiger is the national animal of India',
  1 => 'The tiger is a large carnivorous mammal that roams the forests',
  2 => 'The tiger feeds on animals that also live in the forest',
  3 => 'The tiger does have a coat of orange with black stripes',
  4 => 'Tigers, regardless of their subspecies, are carnivorous animals',
  5 => 'The tiger is a protected species',
];

$out = array_map(function($value) {
    $chars = array_filter(str_split(strtolower($value)),'trim');
    $vals = array_count_values($chars);
    arsort($vals);
    $keys = array_keys($vals);
    return [
        'sentence' => $value,
        'character' => reset($keys),
        'occurrences' => reset($vals),
    ];
}, $sentences);
print_r($out) ;
```

Outputs:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [sentence] => The tiger is the national animal of India
            [character] => i
            [occurrences] => 6
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [sentence] => The tiger is a large carnivorous mammal that roams the forests
            [character] => a
            [occurrences] => 7
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [sentence] => The tiger feeds on animals that also live in the forest
            [character] => e
            [occurrences] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array (
            [sentence] => The tiger does have a coat of orange with black stripes
            [character] => e
            [occurrences] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array (
            [sentence] => Tigers, regardless of their subspecies, are carnivorous animals
            [character] => s
            [occurrences] => 8
        )

    [5] => Array (
            [sentence] => The tiger is a protected species
            [character] => e
            [occurrences] => 6
        )
)
```

To remove special characters:

```
$chars = array_filter(str_split(strtolower($value)),function($val){
    return trim(preg_replace('~\W+~', '', $val));
});
```

Comment: is it removes special characters

Comment: @sarinsurendran What do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: if the sentence contains special characters it wont count as most occuring

Comment: special characters @ # etc

Comment: @sarinsurendran You should use another function than `trim` is the `array_filter()` function. Perhaps a custom function to remove them.

Comment: @sarinsurendran I've updated the answer (see to last part).

Comment: Thanks syscall can you gave me your watsapp no

Comment: @sarinsurendran Yes, a long time ago :) But, what's the point of this question here, please?

Comment: I want to get root folders of gmail and yahoo using imap is it possible

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question.  This is how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `preg_match_all()` with a pattern that matches one letter or number at a time to extract an array of characters, then find the number of occurrences with `array_count_values()`, sort the array by occurrences in descending order, then extract the first key and first value  (which represent the character and count of the highest occurring letter).

Code: ( Demo:  https://3v4l.org/7OZ5d )

```
$sentences = [
    0 => 'The tiger is the national animal of India',
    1 => 'The tiger is a large carnivorous mammal that roams the forests',
    2 => 'The tiger feeds on animals that also live in the forest',
    3 => 'The tiger does have a coat of orange with black stripes',
    4 => 'Tigers, regardless of their subspecies, are carnivorous animals',
    5 => 'The tiger is a protected species',
 ];

foreach  ($sentences as $sentence) {
    $alphanums = preg_match_all ('~[a-z\d]~', strtolower($sentence), $out) ? $out[0] : [];
    // or:  $alphanums = preg_split('~[^a-z\d]*~', strtolower($sentence), null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $occurrences = array_count_values($alphanums);
    arsort($occurrences);
    $result[] = [
        "sentence" => $sentence,
        "character" => key($occurrences), 
        "occurrences" => current($occurrences)
    ];
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: @sarin my method is cleaner / more direct.  Do you want to include digits as well? And underscores?

Comment: Please answer my questions.  Do you want numbers? Underscores?

Comment: Yes digits and underscores avoid

Comment: Remove special characters

Comment: Okay then I will adjust my answer to include digits.

Comment: @sarin your accepted solution makes more/extra function calls and does not exclude underscores, just so you know.

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question.

Comment: What action did you want to take if there is a tie for most occurrences in a sentence?

Comment: please help me to solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49841224/average-and-sum-from-array-in-php

Answer (score 0):

To use [count_chars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)

```
$sentences = [
0 => 'The tiger is the national animal of India',
1 => 'The tiger is a large carnivorous mammal that roams the forests',
2 => 'The tiger feeds on animals that also live in the forest',
3 => 'The tiger does have a coat of orange with **a** black stripe',
4 => 'Tigers, regardless of their subspecies, are carnivorous animals',
5 => 'The tiger is a protected species',
];
```

I grap the occurrences by using count_chars() to $counts and get the max occurrences by using max(). Remove the ASCII codes from the array if occurrences is less than max (**since there might be multiple characters having the same occurrences**).

Convert the remaining ASII code(s) back to characters by suing chr()

```
<?php
    foreach ($sentences as $sentence){
    $string = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $sentence));
    $counts = count_chars($string, 1);
    $max = max($counts);
    foreach ($counts as $key => $count) {
        if ($count < $max) {
            unset($counts[$key]);
        }
    }
    $characters = array_map(function($item){
           return chr($item);
        }, array_keys($counts));
    $result[] = [
        'sentence' => $sentence,
        'character' => implode(',', $characters),
        'occurrences' => $max
    ];
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($result) ,'<pre>';
```

OUTPUT:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [sentence] => The tiger is the national animal of India
        [character] => i
        [occurrences] => 6
    )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sentence] => The tiger is a large carnivorous mammal that roams the forests
            [character] => a
            [occurrences] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sentence] => The tiger feeds on animals that also live in the forest
            [character] => e
            [occurrences] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sentence] => The tiger does have a coat of orange with a black stripe
            [character] => a,e **<== multiple characters**
            [occurrences] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sentence] => Tigers, regardless of their subspecies, are carnivorous animals
            [character] => s
            [occurrences] => 8
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sentence] => The tiger is a protected species
            [character] => e
            [occurrences] => 6
        )

)
```

To count only alphabets:

```
$string = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', $sentence));
```

DEMO: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2fb793031cd172507d8a464b1096b1b2bb73046

Comment: sarin surendran create new post for new question please